# Can we have projectors in typeorm's findOne as we can have in MongoDb's method?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am just curious about if we can provide projectors in typeorm's findOne method? I am using postgres databse.

What I need is just an id from a table for provided email. What I am getting is all the details of the user.

```
repository.findOne({email: 'abc@abc.com'})
```

This gives me all the details. However I just want to extract id of that particular user

Can we pass projectors to the above query? for e.g.

```
repository.findOne({email: 'email'},{id:1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possibly. You need to pass options to your `findOne` function so your code would look like this:

```js
async getOne(email: string): Partial<RepositoryEntity> {
  const foundRow = repository.findOne({
    where: {
      email: email
    },
    select: 'id'
  });
  return foundRow;
}
```

OR

```js
async getOne(email: string): Partial<RepositoryEntity> {
  const foundRow = repository.findOne(
   { email: email },
   { select: 'id' }
  );
  return foundRow;
}
```

You can see the source code where the types are defined [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/repository/Repository.ts#L285)

Comment: Is there anyway we can define fields that we do not want. `!select : ['id']`?